# Can I use curly braces instead of #pragma region?

Tags: c, scope

I'm developing code for an arduino based board, and I'm using VSCode, as I find it better than the Arduino IDE.

Now, in some parts of the code, I like to group certain statements together, to organise the code better. In C# (using Visual Studio) I would use `#region NAME` to do this. The C variant of this is `#pragma region`, however, I find this clutters the code, and isn't quite as clean as I would want it.

Instead I thought of using curly braces `{}`, to achieve something similar, but to my understanding the compiler uses them to declare scope right? So would using them like this:

```
char *data;

{ 
    free(data); 
}
```

produce any odd behaviour? From what I've tried the compiler doesn't seem to mind, but maybe I just haven't tried enough cases.

So, I guess what I want to know is: Would using curly braces in this way be detrimental to general coding in C?

Comment: *"I like to group certain statements together"* - why we rejoiced with the death of line editors and the embracing of whitespace, indentation, etc. There's no reason to use braces; use those for what they're intended: scope.

Comment: When you open a scope all the scope variables will be recognize in the scope only

Comment: Technically what you would write works as expected. However, in a code review I would reject the code.

Comment: Just use whitespace and comments. You're massively overcomplicating this if you want compiler support for something that only affects reading comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compound statement forms a block scope.

So for example this code snippet

```
int x;

int y = 10;

x = y;
```

is not equivalent tp

```
int x;

{    
    int y = 10;
}

x = y;
```

In the last case the compiler will issue an error that the identifier `y` is not declared.

Also using redundant braces makes a code less readable and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Arduino is not C only C++.
2. The best way of organizing the code in C++ is to use classes and structures.
3. In C# region is used to collapse and expand the code in the editor when outlining and has no effect on the code execution. Arduino IDE does not have any of those fancy editor features.
4. Compound statement in C or C++ is something completely different than the `#region` in C#. It creates a new scope that affects the compilation and execution of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Using blocks to group statements and set them off is fine for suitable purposes. One situation I encountered from time to time was when a matrix needed separate processing for its first and last rows, due to border effects. Then the code could look like:

```
{
    int row = 0;

    //  Code for first row.
}

for (int row = 1; row < N-1; ++row)
{
    //  Code for middle rows.
}

{
    int row = N-1;

    //  Code for last row.
}
```

Often the code was largely similar for the three cases, and using blocks each of them made that similarity more visually apparent to the reader. At the same time, having the same level of indentation for each of the cases made the differences easier to see.

Similarly, blocks can organize sections of a function that are semi-repetitive but do not involve loops (and are not involved enough to deserve functions of their own, or that use so many variables that passing them parameters would be a mess).

Blocks are well defined by the C standard and will not produce any “odd behavior.”